# How to identify which UI object is selected in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, uitableview

In this case, I have 2 `QTableView`s in my form and I am making a copy function to copy and paste in Excel, but to make the function I need to declare a model from the table I am copying:

```
QAbstractItemModel *abmodel = ui->tableview1->model();
QItemSelectionModel  *model = ui->tableview1->selectionModel();
QModelIndexList list = model->selectedIndexes();
```

so I am making an "if" to for the declaration depending on which QTableView I have selected:

```
if(ui->tableview1(selected)){
    QAbstractItemModel *abmodel = ui->tableview1->model();
    QItemSelectionModel * model = ui->tableview1->selectionModel();
    QModelIndexList list = model->selectedIndexes();
}

if(ui->tableview2(selected)){
    QAbstractItemModel *abmodel = ui->tableview2->model();
    QItemSelectionModel  *model = ui->tableview2->selectionModel();
    QModelIndexList list = model->selectedIndexes();
}
```

Is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: What do you mean by selected? If the view has focus? Or which element of the view is selected?

Comment: ***What do you mean by selected?*** I am pretty sure that means selected items in the `QTableView`. With that said I don't understand the question / problem.

Comment: ***is there a way to make that happen?*** Make what happen?

Comment: Declare your variables (abmodel and model) before the if () blocks. Initialize them to `nullptr`. Move the `QModelIndexList list = model->selectedIndexes();` line to after the if blocks.

Comment: With that said if you have something selected in both views it will always pick the second.

Comment: with selected table i mean the focus, i have a function that copies from a specific table, but i have 2 tables, i want to use the same function for both tables instead of making one for each table.